# Problem with multi-threading and geoprocessor tool in c#

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, geoprocessing, error-000732, multithreading

**What I am doing:** I am trying to run a geoprocessor tool in a background thread other than UI thread. I am passing `string` path of `arcObjects` and creating that `arcObject` in my background thread. Then I am passing those `arcObjects` to `geoProcessor` tool.

In UI thread, Button's on click method:

```
private void btnFindInterction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<IFeatureLayer> layers = GetAllMapFeatureLayers();

    string featureLayerPath1 = GetFeatureLayerPath(layers[0]);
    string featureLayerPath2 = GetFeatureLayerPath(layers[1]);

    Thread worker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            IFeatureClass featureClass1 = GetFeatureClassFromPath(featureLayerPath1);
            IFeatureClass featureClass2 = GetFeatureClassFromPath(featureLayerPath2);

            var result = RunIntersectTool(featureClass1, featureClass2);
            OnCalculationComplete(intersectedFeatureClasssPath);
        }
    ));

    worker.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    worker.Start();
}
```

The RunIntersectTool method:

```
string RunIntersectTool(IFeatureClass featureClass1, IFeatureClass featureClass2)
{
    IWorkspace workspace = GetTempGDBWorkspace();
    string intersectFeatureClassName = "Intersect_result";
    string intersectFeatureClassPath = workspace.PathName + "\\" + intersectFeatureClassName;
    try
    {
        var gp = new Geoprocessor { OverwriteOutput = true, AddOutputsToMap = false };
        IGpValueTableObject gpValueTableObject = new GpValueTableObjectClass();
        gpValueTableObject.SetColumns(1);
        var inFeature1 = imperviousFeatureClass as object;
        gpValueTableObject.AddRow(inFeature1);
        var inFeature2 = watershedFeatureClass as object;
        gpValueTableObject.AddRow(inFeature2);

        var intersectTool = new Intersect
        {
            in_features = gpValueTableObject,
            out_feature_class = intersectFeatureClassPath 
        };
        gp.Execute(intersectTool, null);
        return intersectFeatureClassPath;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**What problem am I facing:**
The tool runs perfectly in some machines, but gives error in some machine: *"000732 : : Dataset  does not exist or is not supported"* And this error never happen if I don't use threading. I read help files of [Running a geoprocessing tool using background geoprocessing](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//00010000015z000000), but I couldn't find anything that says I can't pass arcObjects.

There is another problem I am facing. Whenever I ran the tool, it works fine first time(in some machines), but gives error when it creates an instance of geoprocessor at second time. Error message: *"Attempted to read or write protected memory"*. I guess this error is also related to multithreading and arcObjects.

Comment: Both featurelayer paths are derived from layers[0], is that a typo?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall: Oh really sorry. It's a typing mistake. But my actual code, I get my layer different way and two layers are always different two layers

Comment: In GetFeatureclassFromPath, are you using Activator.CreateInstance to open the workspace?

Comment: @KirkKuykendall: Actually in my code, I am processing feature class such a way that, I have it's workspace path and type of workspace and the feature class. So I can easily get the feature class from those thing. And I checked that I get the right feature class perfectly using this code

Comment: Right, but just be sure to use [Activator.CreateInstance](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/c778d2bb-eb36-4793-9c89-20795811c5eb.htm#File) instead of `new`.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall: Now I am using Activator.CreateInstance instead of new, but I am curious why CreateInstance is good then new? Doesn't it internally use new?

Comment: Something to do with the "threads in isolation".  Usually a singleton means one instance of the class per _process_.  Using CreateInstance somehow (not sure how) allows a singleton to be one instance of the class per _thread_, eliminating a lot of the marshalling issues.  Did switching to Activator resolve the issue?

Comment: Actually I have made a lot change in my current code and run the geoprocessor tool in a background thread using ExecuteAsync() method. And pass everything as string. That help me to get rid from thread thing and get a working version.